# Best practice to deploy Laravel on remote

Tags: git, laravel, ftp

I have a big doubt: i'm developing a **Laravel website in localhost** and soon i will push it on **Siteground**. What is the best way to do this?

Should i use **FTP** **or** should i push the project into a **GIT** repository and then, accessing via SSH, doing a pull? What does the best practice say in this case?

Thank you!

Comment: Git is going to be a lot easier in most cases. Remember to do `composer install` after.

Comment: If you have SSH access to the server, I would recommend you to use [Deployer](https://deployer.org/blog/how-to-deploy-laravel). Easy to configure with best practices such as versioning, atomic deploys.

Comment: This question is probably quite opinion based and therefore not really suited for SO. But maybe it can be asked in the chat. -- Personally, I would also want to throw into the discussion that things like zero-downtime deployment, maintenance mode, etc. should also be considered.